# Angular 8 : Headers are not properly sent in HttpCliet.post

Tags: angular, httpclient

The following code works:

```js
this.http.post (TGT_IP,body, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).subscribe(
      (val) => {
          console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", 
                      val);

      },
      response => {
          console.log("POST call in error", response);
      },
      () => {
          console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
      });
```

Then I tried the following code:

```js
var body = [0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44];
this.http.post (TGT_IP,
                  body, 
                  { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'octet/stream',
                                              'Accept': 'octet/stream'}),
                    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
                    }).subscribe(
        (val) => {
            console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", 
                        val);

        },
        response => {
            console.log("POST call in error", response);
        },
        () => {
            console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
        });
```

Can you please tell why in this code body is not sent at all ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: Are you sure, that the API gets the body in the right format? I tried the not working code snippet and in the Chrome developer tools under the `Network` tab I saw the request payload as expected. I suspect that the API is not able to parse the body.

Comment: You are right. I got the request. In the original question I changed 'content-type' to 'octet/stream'. In chorme, I can see the requested upload and the headers. But the message sent has no body. Can you please tell what is wrong ?  Thank you very much.

Comment: For some reason, the request sent starts with 'OPTIONS' not with 'POST'. Can you tell why ?

Comment: OPTIONS is what's called preflight request, as explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request and has nothing to do with your logic. The real request should immediately follow.

Comment: The request seems to be fine with the updated code.  I tried it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-get-examples-t3jwgl?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts
The post messages in RequestBin can be found here:
https://requestbin.com/r/enocuett2sko/1b308ko6kuiW9agKCAU5Y4zbODv

Comment: This means, that there is still some problem around the API, that is handeling the POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question seems to be correct. The Angular http post [can be tested here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-get-examples-t3jwgl?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).
The request of the example [can be investigated here](http://requestbin.com/r/enocuett2sko/1b308ko6kuiW9agKCAU5Y4zbODv).

Based on the above example there should be an issue with the API, which is handeling the POST request.

Comment: Thank you very much !